# How to assign member variables temporarily?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators, python-descriptors

I often find that I need to assign some member variables temporarily, *e.g.*

```
old_x = c.x
old_y = c.y
# keep c.z unchanged

c.x = new_x
c.y = new_y

do_something(c)

c.x = old_x
c.y = old_y
```

but I wish I could simply write

```
with c.x = new_x; c.y = new_y:
    do_something(c)
```

or even

```
do_something(c with x = new_x; y = new_y)
```

Can Python's decorators or other language features enable this kind of pattern? (I could modify `c`'s class as needed)

Comment: why not create a new instance？

Comment: @HaifengZhang `c` could have many other variables that aren't modified

Comment: Good call @HaifengZhang, unless `do_something(c)` assigns to other attributes of `c`.

Comment: @MaxB  Create a new Class that contains your modified attributes of instance c, and use `c` for other tasks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Context managers](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) may be used for it easily.

Quoting official docs:

> Typical uses of context managers include saving and restoring various
>   kinds of global state, locking and unlocking resources, closing opened
>   files, etc.

It seems like saving and restoring state is exactly what we want to do here.

Example:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def temporary_change_attributes(something, **kwargs):
    previous_values = {k: getattr(something, k) for k in kwargs}
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        setattr(something, k, v)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        for k, v in previous_values.items():
            setattr(something, k, v)


class Something(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def say_hello(self):
        print("hello", self.x, self.y)


s = Something(1, 2)
s.say_hello()  # hello 1 2
with temporary_change_attributes(s, x=4, y=5):
    s.say_hello()  # hello 4 5
s.say_hello()  # hello 1 2
```

Comment: this is a great answer, but you might want to wrap the internals of the contextmanager in a `try/finally`

Answer (score 5):

I think a [`contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html) should do what you want:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def current_instance(c, temp_x, temp_y):
    old_x, old_y = c.x, c.y
    c.x, c.y = temp_x, temp_y
    yield c
    c.x, c.y = old_x, old_y

with current_instance(c, x, y) as c_temp:
    do_something(c_temp)
```

Answer (score 4):

`mock` provides this functionality, specifically look at the context-manager usage of [`patch.object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object).  It's in core libraries in python3, and [available on pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) for older python.

Setup:

```
>>> class C:
...     def __init__(self, x, y, z):
...         self.x = x
...         self.y = y
...         self.z = z
...         
>>> c = C(0,1,2)
```

Usage demo:

```
>>> print(c.x, c.y, c.z)
0 1 2
>>> with patch.object(c, 'x', 'spam'), patch.object(c, 'y', 'eggs'):
...     print(c.x, c.y, c.z)
...     
spam eggs 2
>>> print(c.x, c.y, c.z)
0 1 2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this natively using `__enter__` and `__exit__`. Simplistic example:

```
class SomeObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3

class Temporary(object):
    def __init__(self, target, **kv):
        self.target = target
        self.to_set = kv
        self.to_restore = {}

    def __enter__(self):
        self.to_restore = map(partial(getattr, self.target), filter(partial(hasattr, self.target), self.to_set.keys()))
        for k,v in self.to_set.items():
            if hasattr(self.target, k):
                self.to_restore[k] = getattr(self.target, k)
            setattr(self.target, k, v)

    def __exit__(self, *_):
        for k,v in self.to_restore.items():
            setattr(self.target, k, v)
        for k in self.to_set.keys():
            if k not in self.to_restore:
                delattr(self.target, k)

o = SomeObject()

print(o.__dict__)
with Temporary(o, a=42, d=1337):
    print(o.__dict__)
print(o.__dict__)
```

Answer (score 2):

Goofy solution

```
>>> class Foo(object):
        def __init__(self):
             self._x = []
             self._y = []


        @property
        def x(self):
           return self._x[-1] or None

        @x.setter 
        def x(self, val):
           self._x.append(val)

        def reset_vals(self):
           if len(self._x) > 1:
              self._x.pop()


>>> bar = Foo()
>>> bar.x = 1
>>> bar.x
1
>>> bar.x = 2
>>> bar.x
2
>>> bar.reset_vals()
>>> bar.x
1
>>> bar.reset_vals()
>>> bar.x
1
```

Still goofy but less so solution

```
>>> class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass


>>> import copy
>>> bar = Foo()
>>> bar.x = 1
>>> bar.x
1
>>> bar2 = copy.copy(bar)
>>> bar2.x
1
>>> bar2.x = 5
>>> bar2.x
5
>>> bar
<__main__.Foo object at 0x0426A870>
>>> bar.x
1
```